# On orthogonal and non-orthogonal coordinate basis conversion

Tags: riemannian-geometry, orthogonality

How exactly are orthogonal and non-orthogonal coordinate bases describes exactly? I'm a beginner in the field and hope to understand them better.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: A basis can be orthogonal with respect to an inner product. This means that $\langle u,v\rangle\neq 0$ if and only if $u=v$, where $u$ and $v$ are basis vectors.

Comment: Are you reading a textbook on linear algebra?

Comment: Yes, I am specifically Vector spaces